# Is there any way to create dstream once streaming context started with out stopping the streaming context

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

I had developed Streaming application using spark streaming.when i start running my application it is creating the dstream for each topic in kafka, then i am starting the streaming context.now i want to create the dstream for new topic got added in kafka with out stopping my streaming context.

Comment: which version of spark you use?

Comment: [pls check SPARK-10320](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10320)

Comment: i am using 1.6 version of spark@Ram Ghadiyaram

Comment: The issue  Which I. Mentioned  have you checked? It's fixed in 2.0

Comment: i had not checked,i will check and get back to you @RamGhadiyaram